# jQuery append multiple <select> to last row in HTML table then send to PHP as an array

Tags: jquery, select, addition

I wonder how to create the below `<select>` "on the fly" using an ADD button and then be able to send the values as an array as POST to a PHP file

**HTML**

```
<select id ='123' class='elements'>
  <option value='1'>First option value</option>
  <option value='2'>Second option value</option>
  <option value='3'>Third option value</option>
</select>
```

Maybe this will send as an array of values?

 
**jQuery**

```
$("#save").click(function() {

var values = {};
$('input.elements').each(function(n, el){
   values[ $(el).attr('id') ] = $(el).val();
});

$.ajax( {
    type : 'POST',
    url : '../update.php',
    data : {value: values}
  });
});
```

I don't know however how to create the `<select>` to the last row of for example `<table id='myTable'>` Anyone got an idea?

**EDIT**
I can successfully add a new row to my table using the below code:

```
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
  $('#myTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>Hello world</td></tr>');
});
```

However when I try to insert my `<select>` inside the row I get error: "missing ) after argument list" and it points to the first apostrophe after `<select id='`

Why is it doint that?

Comment: Maybe you're getting this error because you have a string like this? `'<select id='lol'>...</select>'` Try using quotes around your `id` and other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below pseudo code to create a select option

```
var outerselect  = $('<select><option value='1'>First option value</option>
  <option value='2'>Second option value</option>
  <option value='3'>Third option value</option>
</select>')

$("tablecellelector").append(outerselect)
```

Comment: Hello I added some info to my original question. please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
$("#mytable:last-child").after('<select>....bla bla bla...</select>');
```

EDIT:

after i saw your edit "just now sorry"
i guess your problem is with "quotes"

when you add select

```
$("whatever").append('<select id="">......</select>');
```

you have to 
1- watch out for quotes "a good editor can take care of that"
2- put it inside the `<td> here </td>`

Comment: Hello I added some info to my original question. please take a look!